# Regular expression to avoid exceeding character repeatance on a string

Tags: regex

I have the alphabet {a,b} and I want to give a regular expression which satisfies the set of strings L in which the symbol `a` appears at most twice

This is what I have:

> (b*|a)b*(b*|a|ε)
>   where ε is the empty string

Am I correct or what am I missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [cs.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) h/t @Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simplify this to the following:

> b* (a|ε) b* (a|ε) b*

In PCRE notation that would be:

```
^b*a?b*a?b*$
```

On a side note, I think this kind of questions belongs more to [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The following ones does not match to your expr:

- aba
- aab

`b*a?b*a?b*` is what you need.